# fabric beta testing number of users

Tags: ios, google-fabric, fabric-beta

I am checking the difference b/w fabric for beta testing and itunes testflight. I know for testflight the number of users is limited to 2000. what is the limit for fabric beta testing?

Unable to find that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. Fabric has a limit based on your provisioning profile. This means that it is 100 for non-enterprise and 2000 for enterprise.

Comment: What about android ?

Comment: @Todd Burner thanks for answering. Are these numbers mentioned anywhere in the docs?